# How do I disable that Mathematica orders terms in lexicographic order?

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra, expression-manipulation

I have matrices with entries where the order of the entries is important. Unfortunately *Mathematica* resorts terms in products in a lexicographic order. For example,

```
A = {{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}};
B = {{b1, b2}, {b3, b4}};
Z = {{z1, z2}, {z3, z4}};

Z.B.A

    (* {{a1 (b1 z1 + b3 z2) + a3 (b2 z1 + b4 z2),
         a2 (b1 z1 + b3 z2) + a4 (b2 z1 + b4 z2)}, {a1 (b1 z3 + b3 z4) +
         a3 (b2 z3 + b4 z4),  a2 (b1 z3 + b3 z4) +  a4 (b2 z3 + b4 z4)}} *)
```

I would like that *Mathematica* keeps the order of the terms as they appear in the product, i.e.

```
(* z1 b1 a1 + ... *)
```

How can the lexicographic ordering be disabled?

Comment: You might want to replace `Dot` with `Inner`, where you can direct it to use `NonCommutativeMultiply` in place of `Times`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks! Unforturtunately, Mathematica keeps all the zeroes for matrices that contain zeroes if I use Inner and NonCommutativeMultiply. For example, A = {{a1, a2, 0}, {0, a3, a4}, {0, a3, a4}};
B = {{b1, 0, b2}, {b3, 0, b4}, {b3, 0, b4}};
Z = {{z1, 0, z2}, {0, z3, z4}, {0, z3, z4}}; becomes {{0 ** b3 + a1 ** b1 + a2 ** b3, 0 ** 0 + a1 ** 0 + a2 ** 0, 
  0 ** b4 + a1 ** b2 + a2 ** b4}, {0 ** b1 + a3 ** b3 + a4 ** b3, 
  0 ** 0 + a3 ** 0 + a4 ** 0, 
  0 ** b2 + a3 ** b4 + a4 ** b4}, {0 ** b1 + a3 ** b3 + a4 ** b3, 
  0 ** 0 + a3 ** 0 + a4 ** 0, 0 ** b2 + a3 ** b4 + a4 ** b4}}

Comment: You might want to use a few replacement rules to handle pulling scalars out of noncommutative products. I am pretty sure there are some past threads on MSE that show how this might be done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is related to the [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) attribute of `Times` and `Plus`.  These attributes could be removed permanently with some hacks, but that would break Mathematica.

If you only want to *display* the result in a certain way, but not do calculations with it, it may be safe to remove those attributes temporarily using [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html).

```
Block[{Plus, Times}, With[{result = Z.B.A}, HoldForm[result]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Update**

Jacob is asking how to preserve some of the evaluation rules of `Times`, such as `0*x` → `0` and `1*x` → `x`, while still removing the `Orderless` attribute.  This is possible with `` Internal`InheritedBlock ``.  It works like `Block` in that any modifications to the blocked symbols will be temporary, but it does not remove blocked symbol definitions at the start.  Thus we can selectively remove the `Orderless` attribute.

This is an undocumented function, so the usual caveats apply: it may change behaviour in future versions, it may behave unexpectedly, and it may even crash your kernel (this one has never crashed my kernel, but other internal functions have).

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Plus, Times},
 Unprotect[Plus, Times];
 ClearAttributes[{Plus, Times}, Orderless];
 With[{result = Z.B.A}, HoldForm[result]]
]
```

Comment: regarding `Block[{Plus, Times}, With[{result = Z.B.A}, HoldForm[result]]]` ... why does work?  Does this combination of `Block`, `With` and `HoldForm` somehow drop the attributes from symbols given as the first argument to `Block`?  I don't understand why this would happen.

Comment: @billc "Does this ... somehow drop the attributes from symbols given as the first argument to `Block`?"  Yes, that is exactly what `Block` does. It temporarily removes any definitions associated with those symbols.  See [(559)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/12).